# Why does Rails not document the ability to use accepts_nested_attributes_for on children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

From the rails documentation: "Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the **parent**."

I am able to save attributes on associated records through the **CHILD**. (Which is great... but WHY is this not documented or explained?)

(This project can be cloned from github at: https://github.com/blasto333/Vehicles-Demo/)

**Vehicle Model (Parent)**

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car
  attr_accessible :name, :color, :price, :condition
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: vehicles
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  color      :string(255)
#  price      :string(255)
#  condition  :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#
```

**Car Model (Child)**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicle
  attr_accessible :doors, :sport, :vehicle_attributes
end


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: cars
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  vehicle_id :integer
#  doors      :integer
#  sport      :boolean
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#
```

**Cars Controller**

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @car = Car.new
    @car.build_vehicle
  end

  def create
    Car.create(params[:car])
  end

end
```

**Cars "new" view**

```
<h1>Cars#new</h1>
<%= form_for @car do |car_form| %>
    <%= car_form.fields_for :vehicle do |vehicle_fields| %>
        <%=vehicle_fields.label :name%>: <%=vehicle_fields.text_field :name%><br />
        <%=vehicle_fields.label :color%>: <%=vehicle_fields.text_field :color%><br />
        <%=vehicle_fields.label :price%>: <%=vehicle_fields.text_field :price%><br />
        <%=vehicle_fields.label :condition%>: <%=vehicle_fields.text_field :condition%><br />
    <% end %>
    <%=car_form.label :doors%>: <%=car_form.text_field :doors%><br />
    <%=car_form.label :sport%>: <%=car_form.text_field :sport%><br />
    <%=car_form.submit%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

```
Defines an attributes writer for the specified association(s).
```

It means all associations: `has_many`, `has_one`, `belongs_to`, `habtm`. So... everything looks pretty documented.

Comment: But the rails documentation says:"Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent" - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Yep, but it's not a bug. If you look deeper in sources of this method there easy to see that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` works with all sorts of association: `if reflection = reflect_on_association(association_name); ... ; else: raise ArgumentError, "No association found for name `#{association_name}'. Has it been defined yet?"; end`